# QT : operator after class declaration

Tags: c++, qt

Recently I started working on a QT project, but there are more syntax rules than regular C++.

While declaring class and its constructor, in header file, we simply write

```
class MyObj : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObj(QObject* parent = nullptr, <params>, ...)
    .
    .
    <some more declarations>
private:
    .
    .
    <some more declarations>
};
```

In .cpp file, we can define this constructor as

```
MyObj::MyObj(QObject* parent, <params>) :
    QObject(parent),
    ...
    <some more parameter like arguments, that is what I am exactly asking>
{
    <regular initializations>
}
```

I am asking about the parameter like arguments after the : operator in the first line of declaring an initializing the class.

What are they, why QT needs these?

Note: In QT project examples, you can simply find the "Command Line Writer Async" example. In that project, a proper usage of this fact exists. I am using QT 5.15.

Comment: That's a standard C++ feature called "member initializer lists". They provide a quick way of initializing your classes' base and member variables. See [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; however, that looks different in their definition. Does this "member initialization list" the same thing? Is there any semantic changes for that operator in QT?

Comment: QT cannot magically change the language. You are still writing C++. Can you explain how it looks different?

Comment: I don't know :). But it seemed differently. Does the member initialization list feature a necessity? Cannot we properly define the same think via methods and functions? @Botje

Comment: @Voursstreds In certain situations you can pull off without member init list by assigning members in constructor body (like Java does). But you cannot do that if a) you need to initialize base class object, like in the example; b) you have `const` members; c) you have reference members; d) you have other non-assignable members (like `std::mutex`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an operator. That's a standard c++ feature called [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

For example

```
class Test
{
private:
    int test_val;
    some_type some_test;
public:
    Test() : 
    test_val(7),
    some_test()
    {}
    .
    .
    //whatever
}
```

In this example, when an instance of `Test` is constructed, the members are constructed(or initialized) as shown in the code. `test_val` is initialized with 7, and `some_test` is constructed via the call of the default constructor of `some_type`.

If you written the code above as follows.

```
class Test
{
private:
    int test_val;
    some_type some_test;
public:
    Test()
    {
        test_val=7;
        some_test=some_type(args...);
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to.

```
class Test
{
private:
    int test_val;
    some_type some_test;
public:
    Test() : 
    test_val(),
    some_test()
    {
        test_val=7;
        some_test=some_type(args...);
    }
}
```

Which means that every member is constructed(or initialized) by-default, and then is copy-constructed as requested in the body of `Test::Test()`.
The mere purpose for `member initialization list` is to specify how the members should be initalized

> Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified. For bases and non-static data members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

Comment: Is it a really need? In a function-method, all of those can be done it seems. Is there anything that can be done by "member initialization list" but cannot be done by standard functions-methods and their arguments?

Comment: See the quote in the answer.